# Incorrect number of indices while increasing brightness of a color image

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Code works fine while reading a gray scale image to perform brightness. But same code doesn't work with color image.
How to perform brightness operation from a color image?

While reading the image using cv2.imread at the argument 0 works fine but I tried with 1 it doesn't work as 0 is for gray scale image and 1 for color image.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('image1.jpg',1)

height = img.shape[0]
width = img.shape[1]
brightness = 100

for i in np.arange(height):
    for j in np.arange(width):
        a = img.item(i,j)
        b = a + brightness
        if b > 255:
            b = 255
        img.itemset((i,j), b)

cv2.imwrite('brightness.jpg', img)

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I expect a color image to be read and perform brightness operation but it is showing ValueError: incorrect number of indices for array

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a colored image has multiple channels for the different color (example, RGB or RGBA) so when you do `img.item(i,j)` you are missing the third dimension (the three color channels). You can add another for loop that loops over each of the color channels but you can also just use numpy's `minimum` function to make it more efficient (i.e. add 255 to the values of your image and if it's greater than 255 it will use 255).

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('image1.jpg',1)
brightness = 100
np.minimum(img + brightness, 255)
cv2.imwrite('brightness.jpg', img)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use **OpenCV normalize** to stretch the image to full dynamic range (0 to 255).

Here are two output results depending upon the min and max stretch limits. Note that normalize works on float data and the min and max values are nominally stretched to full range of 0 to 1. But we ned to clip the results to this range and then scale them to the range 0 to 255 before saving as uint8 for output, if the min and max values are outside the range of 0 to 1.

```
The first result is stretched to min and max of 0 to 1.

The second result is stretched to min and max of 0 to 1.2 in order to make it even brighter.
```

Image:

[image]

```
#!/bin/python3.7

import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread("zelda1_bm20_cm20.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# normalize float versions
norm_img1 = cv2.normalize(img, None, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
norm_img2 = cv2.normalize(img, None, alpha=0, beta=1.2, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)

# scale to uint8
norm_img1 = (255*norm_img1).astype(np.uint8)
norm_img2 = np.clip(norm_img2, 0, 1)
norm_img2 = (255*norm_img2).astype(np.uint8)

# write normalized output images
cv2.imwrite("zelda1_bm20_cm20_normalize1.jpg",norm_img1)
cv2.imwrite("zelda1_bm20_cm20_normalize2.jpg",norm_img2)

# display input and both output images
cv2.imshow('original',img)
cv2.imshow('normalized1',norm_img1)
cv2.imshow('normalized2',norm_img2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Min and Max (0 to 1):

[image]

Min and Max (0 to 1.2):

[image]